# Networking Issue with Linux under Azure Site Recovery

Tags: linux, linux-networking, azure, centos7

I am trying to protect some on-prem CentOS 7.2 VMs running in Hyper-V using Azure Site Recovery. I have the replications to Azure running successfully, but when doing a test failover I cannot get connected to Linux via SSH. I can't even successfully ping the system. Even testing from another system running in that same virtual network in Azure I cannot reach this Linux server. Azure says it is up, but it appears networking isn't working correctly.

I removed Network Manager from the system, and I changed the system to use DHCP based on a couple of possible issues I found Googling around, but still I get the same issue. Anybody have any experience using Linux with ASR and know what might be happening here?